# Connecting a data source to dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database

I am trying to connect a data source to a dropdown list. I have people called "instructors" in my database and i want their names and surnames in my dropdown list. Here is the related part of code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Surname] FROM [InstructorTable] ORDER BY [Name]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The problem is, i only see their names, not surnames in the dropdown list. What can be the problem here? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is `DropDownList composite datatextfield`. This Can be done by Using sql statements.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] + '' + [Surname] as FullName FROM [InstructorTable] ORDER BY [Name]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

then in your code `DataTextField="FullName"`

check [binding-multiple-fields-to-listbox-in-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143639/binding-multiple-fields-to-listbox-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thanks, it works when i said test query, but it does not work in the browser and gives an error saying "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'" do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Because the dropdown takes only only one field.

You need to concat Name & Surname in the select query and you will be fine.

Update

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT Concat([Name], [Surname]) as CombinedName FROM [InstructorTable
```

Comment: Thanks, but where can i concatenate them? This is .aspx file, not a .cs file so i do not know where i can concatenate them? Can you tell me?

Comment: In your Selectcommand. see updated answer (assumption SQL server is used)

Comment: I use sql server but it gives an error saying that concat is not a recognized built-in function name